# Which trackers to use for a torrent?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, bittorrent

I'm new to bittorrent seeding and I'm experimenting with an audio file that I'm adding to create my first torrent. I'm using transmission but at the field where I should add trackers I'm stuck and I don't know how to add a tracker. Could you help me maybe link to a list of good known bittorrent trackers for my file? It's a mixed audio file that I want to seed with bittorrent and using it legally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to add trackers](http://tutzone.org/how-to-create-torrent-file-and-upload/) is good link for you. Here they have explained how to create a new torrent file and how to upload it and of course they have told how to add trackers and which are working.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in general, as long as the tracker is actually up, it shouldn't be an issue.  [Openbitorrent](http://openbittorrent.com/) and [publicbitorrent](http://publicbt.com/) would be good options. You might also want to consider using a [webseed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29#Web_seeding) - an easy way would be to upload the file somewhere and use [burnbit](http://burnbit.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with openbittorrent och added that tracker which as far as I understand is just adding the string `http://openbittorrent.com` to the so-called tracker list in my bittorrent application (transmission for ubuntu).